# Tell PyCharm code generated fields of class

Tags: python, python-2.7, pycharm, docstring

As a minimal case I have a class `Example` that works like in abstract capacity for a range of other classes.

```
class Example(object):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        for key, value in kwargs.items():
            setattr(self, key, value)            

class Test(Example):
    def __init__(self, foo='bar'):
        super(Test, self).__init__(foo=foo)
```

In the real case, `Example` does more things.

Is there a way to on `Test` inform PyCharm that `Test` will have one field `Test.foo` and even better, let it know that `foo` is expected to be a string?

*To be clear, consider delegating the setting of fields from `Example` to `Test` not possible.*

The closest I've gotten is the `@ivar` of Epydoc, but I can't get it to work

Comment: AFAIK, you can't. If you define the members of an object dynamically, you have to forget about hints. You could define class attributes on `Test` that will be "shadowed" by instance attributes, but it is not worth the price. Just live with it.

Comment: *sigh*, oh well, but thank's for the answer.

Comment: Yeah pitty, but Pycharm would have to be extremely smart to understand the code and offer you hinting. In many cases I avoid "dynamic" code in favour of "manually typed" code just to have a little bit more security and enjoy the annotations as well. At the end it is a general problem of dynamically typed languages... IDEs can't do too much.

Answer (score 8):

As others have mentioned, you can't. However, you can tell PyCharm to accept missing attributes with `@DynamicAttrs`:

```
class Example(object):
   """
   @DynamicAttrs
   """
   def __init__(self, **kwargs):
      for key, value in kwargs.items():
         setattr(self, key, value)
```

**Update:**
If Python3.5 is an option, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34230618/python-3-5-type-hinting-dynamically-generated-instance-attributes) about using type hints for dynamic attributes.

Answer (score 3):

I had exactly same problem you are facing.
I didn't want code suggestion I just wanted PyCharm to stop warning me about undefined attributes ( `foo is not attribute of class Test` )

I couldn't fix the code hinting problem but I overcame the warning by implementing `Example` class like that

```
class Example(object):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        for key, value in kwargs.items():
            setattr(self, key, value)            

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        """
        Does absolutely nothing, only for pycharm to stop complaining about massing attributes
        This function is *only* called when python fail to find certain attribute, so it always raises exception
        """
        raise AttributeError("Attribute %s is not part of %s class" % (name, self.__class__.__name__))
```